# My app closes because of device low memory

Tags: android, android-intent, backup, android-intentservice

I am developing an app  that uses intent services to backup some files. The app works fine and does not crash. However, when I start an app in background the app will close sometimes when it runs for two days or sometimes in one night only.

Is it because that device is low on memory and my app doesn't close correctly?

Is there any intent i.e I handle this condition in my app and I will show the reason to my user  why the last process stopped.

Comment: There is `Intent` for Crash but you should catch crash in some Log file for that and check your crashing logcat carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Yep. Your problem is indeed due to device running low on memory.

When resources turn low Android simply disposes of running services, such as yours.

What happen next depends on you

**Declare as sticky**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Adding the above to your service will force Android to **restart it after killing**, once resources 
go up again .

If a running service is crucial for your system and you do not want it auto-killed under any
circumstance (tip: most of the time this is *not* what you want), you can do it by declaring
it to be a **foreground service**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setTicker("ticker text").setContentTitle("title text").setContentText("content")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOngoing(true).setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendIntent);
Notification notif = builder.build();
notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
startForeground(NOTIF_ID, notif);
```

Final note: [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) spawns only a single thread on which all requests are executed.
This works fine in many cases. But, when it comes to IO-bound execution, you will usually get
better performance using multiple threads.

So, and only if performance is an issue, consider using e.g. a multi-thread pool for the job:

```
ThreadFactory threadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();
ThreadPoolExecutor executorPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
      MIN_NUM_THREADS, MAX_NUM_THREADS, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, ...);

...
executorPool.execute(new MyWorkerThread(params));
```

Where the first two params received by ThreadPoolExecutor constructor set min and max number
of concurrently active threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these to measure the memory.

```
Gdx.app.getJavaHeap();
Gdx.app.getNativeHeap();
```

Since you app runs on the background, maybe you could save the values for later study?

Comment: u mean to say i just get heap size and mention some verification that if device have low heap then stop it process.Is it your way to handle the error??

Comment: What I mean is, start your application and monitor the amount of memory. If it is stable you will know that it was not shut down due to insufficient memory.